# body-parser parse by index

Tags: node.js, express, query-string, body-parser

Using DataTables for front end and nodejs+express+mongoose+body-parser on back end

When I tried to delete a row in the table, this is what is passed to backend (HTTP DELETE)

```
action:remove
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][_id]:5957c1368225f446c84dde9b
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][updatedAt]:2017-07-01T15:35:18.407Z
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][createdAt]:2017-07-01T15:35:18.407Z
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][account]:test@gmail.com
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][name]:Beryl Welch
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][number]:074-882-4899 x241
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][email]:Naomi.Lemke@yahoo.com
data[5957c1368225f446c84dde9b][__v]:0
```

I am trying to get the value _id out of the DELETE request 5957c1368225f446c84dde9b

I am trying to figure out how to access this value without knowing it in the first place as this value is actually the ID of the document to delete from mongo

If I stringify req.query, this is what I get

```
{"action":"remove","data":{"5957c3e07c5c3c150c10f5cb":{"_id":"5957c3e0
7c5c3c150c10f5cb","updatedAt":"2017-07-01T15:46:40.635Z","createdAt":"2017-
07-01T15:46:40.635Z","account":"test@gmail.com","name":"Breanna 
Ratke","number":
"(055) 304-7364 x20329","email":"Mathilde.Moore51@hotmail.com","__v":"0"}}}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
/T

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by getting the parent key in the return object and running a `for in` from there to get to the fields we want. I wrapped that in a function so we can query the return object for any fields (account, _id, etc.).

```js
var res = {"action":"remove","data":{"5957c3e07c5c3c150c10f5cb":{"_id":"5957c3e07c5c3c150c10f5cb","updatedAt":"2017-07-01T15:46:40.635Z","createdAt":"2017-07-01T15:46:40.635Z","account":"test@gmail.com","name":"Breanna Ratke","number":
"(055) 304-7364 x20329","email":"Mathilde.Moore51@hotmail.com","__v":"0"}}}

function getValueFromObj(desiredField) {
  for (var data in res.data) {
    for (var k in res.data[data]) { // res.data[data] is the "data" object
      if (k === desiredField && res.data[data].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        return res.data[data][k];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(getValueFromObj('_id'));     // 5957c3e07c5c3c150c10f5cb
console.log(getValueFromObj('account')); // test@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot Andy.
This also worked for me:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body["data"]).toString();
```